# Trouble running Path of Exile

Tags: technical-issues, path-of-exile

Okay, so it installs fine, I've checked my specs, I meet the minimum requirements, but when I try to run it all I get is a loading screen, then it goes black. Any suggestions?

Comment: How long did you wait before you gave up? the loading when launching the game is pretty stupidly long.

Comment: Around 10 minutes I suppose. How long would you estimate it takes?

Comment: For me it takes ~2-3 minutes. I've read that some people had loadtimes of 8-9 minutes, but the latest patch improved it. Mayba give it ~20 minutes to see if that is the actual problem, if it doesn't work come through after that long, it'll probably never get through. Do you have it installed through steam or not?